# Trying to throw exception causes segfault

Tags: c++, exception, segmentation-fault, throw

I have this chunk of code that throws an exception when the top pointer is null. However, it enters the if statement and immediately segfaults. I am not changing values of this pointer anywhere and I know from debugging that it enters the statement.

```
std::string LinkedStack::pop() {
if (!top) {
    throw (std::out_of_range(""));
}
//...
```

This is the catch part, I cannot edit this as it was provided by my professor for the assignment.

```
 try {
    testStack.pop();
    std::cout << "FAIL: should have thrown exception from pop"<< std::endl;
}
catch(std::out_of_range& e){
    printAssertEquals("Can't pop from an empty stack", e.what());
}
```

I am using Clion IDE and running a windows machine if that matters at all. I have a feeling that this could be a system problem as everyone I've talked to hasn't been able to see where the problem is. Thanks!

EDIT: also this is the output message that it prints when it crashes, I see it's a segfault in the debugger though:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():

Process finished with exit code 3

Comment: What does `printAssertEquals` do? Does it rethrow the exception? Because from the message you're getting, you have an uncaught exception. Other than that, we have too little information. Also `this could be a system problem` I doubt that.

Comment: It might help if you provided a complete example (all the code needed to produce an executable) that is at the same time minimal (take out all the code not needed to reproduce the segfault). Sometimes being able to reproduce an issue is the most efficient way to figure out what is going on. _(Hint: one simplification might be -- for debugging purposes -- to replace `printAssertEquals` with a message to `std::cout`. You can always change it back once the segfault has been solved.)_